# .htaccess - alias all www-only requests to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to install the wonderful Concrete5 CMS to use as my main site engine - the problem is it has about 15 different files and directories, and they clutter up my root. I'd really like to move it to a `/_concrete/` subdirectory, and still maintain it in the domain root.

htaccess has never been my strong suit - after a lot of research and learning, and a lot of error 500s, my frustration is overriding my pride and I'm posting here. Here's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish:

- Any requests that come through `www.domain.com` are forwarded to `www.domain.com/_concrete/`, except in the case of an existing file.
- The end-user URL **shouldn't** change - they will still see the site as `www.domain.com`, even though they're being served `www.domain.com/_concrete/`.
- Multiple subdomains exist on this site as sub-folders within the root - thus, only requests coming through `www.domain.com` should be redirected.

Here's the closest I got with my htaccess, which produces an error 500:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^_concrete
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _concrete/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is the result of 4 hours of sweat and blood (mostly blood), so I have to be close. I'm hoping one of your fine minds can point out a stupid mistake and put this thing to rest swiftly. Thanks for your time!

---

**Addendum:** I previously posted [.htaccess - alias domain root to subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726978/htaccess-alias-domain-root-to-subfolder) a while ago, which got me started. Please don't fall into the trap of thinking it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is Internal Redirection loop,
`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` contains the Absolute system path of the file (/home/user/...) not the Url Path,
your third condition states that the system path to the requested file starts with `_concrete` which will never be true.

to reproduce what happens, let's say for example a request is made to `/contact` (which is not a file) :
 the url pass all rewrite conditions and the request is being internally redirected to `/_concrete/contact`, now Mod_Rewrite will reexecute the htaccess again (`L` flag sto only the current run, if the url has been changed, rules will be applied again to the new url)

so, the new url `/_concrete/contact` will also pass all conditions and rewritten to `/_concrete/_concrete/contact`  and so on ...
which will produce a Redirection loop and Apache will output the 500 Error message

to solve this problem, you have to change your third condition with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_concrete
```

Comment: Beautiful - I wish I could accept this twice. You've saved me so much pain. Cheers!

Comment: glad it helps, I've added some explanation to strengthen your suit :)